# Proof of a lemma needed for proving a second result

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So i have a question that i have to prove, but in order to prove it i need to prove the following lemma. It is a typical set theory sort of lemma, so i feel the proofs are almost complete, but personally i feel that i may have taken the liberty of one assumption or two that may not be allowed.

Let $X $ and $Y $ be two sets. Let $f: X-->Y $ be a bijection.

A) if $U\subset  X $, then $(f^{-1 (inverse)}(u))^{-1 (preimage)}) = f(u) $  B) if $U\subset X$, then $f^{-1}(f(u) = u$
C) if $V\subset Y$, then $f(f^{-1}(v))= v$

proofs:

a) --> let $f(x)\in (f^{-1 (inverse)}(u))^{-1 (preimage)})$  $\implies x\in f^{-1(inverse)}(u) = U \subset X$ $\implies f(x)\in f(u)\subset Y$(by bijection property. therefore $(f^{-1 (inverse)}(u))^{-1 (preimage)}) \subset f(u) $
<-- let $f(x) \in f(u)$ $\implies x\in f^{-1(inverse)} = U\subset X$ $\implies f(x)\in (f^{-1 (inverse)}(u))^{-1 (preimage)} = f^{-1}(u) \subset f^{-1}(X) = Y$

b) --> let $x\in f^{-1}(f(u))$ $\implies f(x) \in f(u)$ (by direct image)
$\implies x\in u\subset X$ by inverse of bijection. 
therefore $f^{-1}(f(u))\subset U$

<--  let $x\in U$ $\implies f(x) \in f(u)$ $\implies f^{-1}(f(x))\in f^{-1}(f(u))$ $\implies x\in f^{-1}(f(u))$ therefore $u\subset f^{-1}(f(u))$

c) --> let $f(x)\in f(f^{-1}(v)$ $\implies x\in f^{-1}(v)$ by bijection $\implies f(x) \in V \subset Y$ therefore $f(f^{-1}(v) \subset V$

<-- let $f(x) \in V$ $\implies f^{-1}(f(x)) \in f^{-1}(v)$ $\implies f(f^{-1}(f(x)) \in f(f^{-1}(v)$ $\implies f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(v))$ therefore $v\subset f(f^{-1}(v)$

also i was getting tied up between the use of the inverse and the preimage. is the inverse for points of a set and the pre-image for sets themselves?

note: before anybody helps can someone please tell me the right latex code to put line breaks between all of my implications? then I could at least make it legible to read. Cheers

Comment: There are three ways to solve the $f^{-1}$ confusion. (1) Use lowercase to denote points and uppercase to denote sets; (2) Write $f^{-1}[U]$ for preimage and $f^{-1}(u)$ as inverse; (3) Write explicitly that $F$ will denote the preimage function and use it specifically instead of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: ok going to go through that now. how about line breaks?